# Building wheel for simpletraj (setup.py) ... error

Tags: pip, python-3.5

Especially, I am having difficulties installing the Simpletraj library in command prompt. I have already installed the dependencies such as Microsoft C++ 14.0. Still, I am getting the error message. The error message is appended below:

Building wheel for simpletraj (setup.py) ... error

ERROR: Failed building wheel for simpletraj
  Running setup.py clean for simpletraj
Failed to build simpletraj
Installing collected packages: simpletraj
    Running setup.py install for simpletraj ... error

Comment: Text of the command(s) and the full traceback, please.

Comment: solved the problem. Thanks